# Legal use of non-trailing function template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, default-parameters, function-templates

While debugging someone's nasty macro-generated code, I saw that MSVC++ alone was not happy with something akin to the following function template declaration:

```
template <typename ...Vs, typename>
void foo();
```

Fair enough. I was puzzled though as to why GCC and Clang would compile that. I added a definition of `foo` to the declaration above, and now GCC also produces a compilation error (Clang remains content). This code is below:

```
template <typename ...Vs, typename>
void foo();

template <typename ...Vs, typename = int>
void foo() {  }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  foo<char,float>();
  return 0;
}
```

Is Clang right or wrong? I note that GCC and MSVC++ can compile if the declaration is removed.

Comment: [tag:language-lawyer]?

Comment: Only 5 tags are allowed :)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? 2010 doesn't support parameter packs.

Comment: The latest version: VS 2019 version 16.2.0

Answer (score 5):

Clang is correct. The template [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Explanation) may appear earlier if the following parameters have default arguments.

> In a primary class template, the template parameter pack must be the final parameter in the template parameter list. In a function template, the template parameter pack may appear earlier in the list provided that all following parameters can be deduced from the function arguments, or have default arguments:
>
> ```
> template<typename... Ts, typename U> struct Invalid; // Error: Ts.. not at the end
>
> template<typename ...Ts, typename U, typename=void>
> void valid(U, Ts...);     // OK: can deduce U
> // void valid(Ts..., U);  // Can't be used: Ts... is a non-deduced context in this position
>
> valid(1.0, 1, 2, 3);      // OK: deduces U as double, Ts as {int,int,int}
> ```

Then given `foo<char,float>();`, `Vs` is deduced as `char, float`, and the 2nd template argument would be `int`.

From the standard, [[temp.param]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#13)

> If a template-parameter of a primary class template, primary variable template, or alias template is a template parameter pack, it shall be the last template-parameter. A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) of the function template or has a default argument ([temp.deduct]).

And about the behavior of gcc and msvc,

> GCC and MSVC++ will successfully compile if the declaration is removed.

Gcc and MSVC seem failing to merge the [default template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Default_template_arguments), which appear in the declarations and the definition should be merged.

> Default template arguments that appear in the declarations and the
>   definition are merged similarly to default function arguments:
>
> ```
> template<typename T1, typename T2 = int> class A;
> template<typename T1 = int, typename T2> class A;
> // the above is the same as the following:
> template<typename T1 = int, typename T2 = int> class A;
> ```

Comment: I just noticed that GCC and MSVC++ will successfully compile if the declaration is removed.

Comment: @user2023370 I think gcc is wrong on it; see my revised answer.

Comment: We could also have multiple SFINAE overloads.

Comment: What you write is correct but I don't think catch the problem of the question; please, could you give a look at my answer?

Comment: @max66 I'm not sure.. But I suppose the rule is same for the function default arguments, like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PFsqcSvYQLKXlwAG).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but seems to me that g++ is right and clang++ is wrong.

songyuanyao is right saying that a template parameter isn't necessarily in last position when the "following parameters [...] have default arguments".

But g++ agree with this because if you add the default argument in the declaration, removing it from the definition,

```
template <typename ...Vs, typename = int>
void foo();

template <typename ...Vs, typename>
void foo() {  }

int main ()
{
  foo<char,float>();
}
```

both compilers (also g++) compile without problems.

So the point, IMHO, is: can we express template default arguments also in the function definition (function definition only; when preceded by a function declaration) or only in function declaration(s) ?

Isn't completely clear to me but, reading the C++17 standard, i see (17.1.9)

> A default template-argument may be specified in a template declaration. A default template-argument shall not be specified in the template-parameter-list s of the definition of a member of a class template that appears outside of the member’s class. A default template-argument shall not be specified in a friend class template declaration. If a friend function template declaration specifies a default template-argument , that declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of the function template in the translation unit

So default template arguments are surely accepted in "declaration"s, not in "definition".

I repeat: not sure because is explicitly excluded in case of a definition of "a member of a class template that appears outside of the member’s class", not in case of a generic definition after a declaration.

Anyway, I don't see explicated that a default template argument can be accepted in a definition that is preceded by a declaration.

In 17.1.10 we have

> The set of default template-argument s available for use is obtained by merging the default arguments from all prior declarations of the template in the same way default function arguments are

Again: "declarations", not "definition".

So I suppose that g++ is wrong because a default template-argument shouldn't be accepted in a definition after a declaration.

Comment: It's not easy for me (as a non-native English speaker), but I interpret 17.1.10 as *the set of default template-arguments are merged from the default arguments of all prior declarations and the default argument specified by current declaration or definition*.

Comment: @songyuanyao - Some problem (non-native English speaker). I find your interpretation reasonable but, unfortunately, I haven't found, in the standard, something explicit or an example involving default template arguments in function definitions (not declarations). Anyway, what I mean is that the point of this question is exactly this: not if a template parameter pack can be followed by a template parameter with default argument but if a default template parameter can be expresses in a function definition (not declaration).

Comment: Yes I got your point. And I'm not sure, :) As you said there's no explicit descriptions in the standard.